How to create monthly raster in such a way that it's pixel values are less than the next month?
I have two montly land surface temperature (LST) rasters from Landsat 8, for the months July and August. The LST values for August are slightly higher than the pixels values from the July raster.
I want to create another raster, for the month June and I want its pixel values to be slightly less than the pixel values of the month July (I think it's natural for this to happened in reality). I thought to take the mean (average) of the two rasters but then the end result would have been pixel values between the July and August, which is not what I want.
How can create the raster for the month June in such a way that will have pixel values less than the July's raster?
A reproducible example:
library(terra)
library(ggfortify)

# extent and crs
ext <- ext(0, 10, 0, 10)
crs <- "EPSG:27700"

# rast for july
july_raster <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, ext=ext, crs=crs)
values(july_raster) <- runif(ncell(july_raster), min=20, max=30) # Example LST values in °C

# rast for july
august_raster <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, ext=ext, crs=crs)
values(august_raster) <- values(july_raster) + runif(ncell(august_raster), min=0.5, max=1.5)

# plot
plot(july_raster, main="July LST")
plot(august_raster, main="August LST")

# linear model
s <- c(july_raster, august_raster)
names(s) <- c("july_raster", "august_raster")

m <- lm(august_raster ~ ., s)
summary(m)

# normality check
autoplot(m)

In the above example, I created two raster layers for the afforementioned two months (July and August) and I checked if their relationship is linear (by checking the residuals of a regression). Using my original raster files, their relationship is linear as well.
R 4.4.1,  terra 1.7.78, Windows 11.

Why can't you just subtract a constant from the July raster, or divide it by a number bigger than 1? june_raster = july_raster / 1.1 for example? Am I missing some subtlety in your problem?

That was easy... I haven't thought of that

The terra package gives you rasters that can be operated on arithmetically.
Create a sample raster:
r = rast(matrix(sample(12), 3, 4))

Scale it down by 0.9:
r2 = r * 0.9

and then all the values in r2 are less than the corresponding values in r.
If you want to add a bit of noise, but still keep the values below, scale by a raster of random numbers between 0 and 1:
r3 = r * rast(matrix(runif(ncell(r)),3,4))

If you plot the values and add the equality line (0,1) you'll see the new values are below the old ones, but randomly.
plot(r, r3)
abline(0,1)

